# How to resolve AddressAccessDeniedException in WCFhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I created a simple WCF service and hosted in a console application.
After configuring all the endpoints I got an exception as below.

[image]

Below in my configuration file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="HelloService.HelloService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="HelloService" contract="HelloService.IHelloService" binding="basicHttpBinding"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="HelloService" contract="HelloService.IHelloService" binding="netTcpBinding"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8081/"/>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8090/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Help me how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because of permission problem in your operating system. 
Your operating system does not allow WCF service on a specified port.
All you need to do is to create an exception for that port.
Below is the procedure:

1. Click Start
2. Run **cmd prompt** as an **administrator**
3. type **netsh.exe** and press enter
4. type **http add urlacl url=http://+:*8081*/*Service*/ user=*administrator*** and press enter.

Here you need to observe three points

8081: is your port on which you need access. Replace it with your own port number.

Service: this is your sesrvice name. Ex: MyWeatherService

administrator: you have to give access to the ser you want on your computer. In my case I gave access to adminitrator. Ex: you can give access to the puppy if there is an user named puppy on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if the WCF service can user port 80

Answer (score 0):

run your application as administrator, it will resolve the issue.